# Python-PPTX: Changing table style or adding borders to cells

Tags: python, border, powerpoint, python-pptx

I've started putting together some code to take Pandas data and put it into a PowerPoint slide. The template I'm using defaults to Medium Style 2 - Accent 1 which would be fine as changing the font and background are fairly easy, but there doesn't appear to be an implemented portion to python-pptx that allows for changing cell borders. Below is my code, open to any solution. (Altering the XML or changing the template default to populate a better style would be good options for me, but haven't found good documentation on how to do either). Medium Style 4 would be ideal for me as it has exactly the borders I'm looking for.

```
import pandas
import numpy
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

#Template Location
tmplLoc = 'C:/Desktop/'

#Read in Template
prs = Presentation(tmplLoc+'Template.pptx')

#Import data as Pandas Dataframe - dummy data for now
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(10,10),columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

#Determine Table Header
header = list(df.columns.values)

#Determine rows and columns
in_rows = df.shape[0]
in_cols = df.shape[1]

#Insert table from C1 template
slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[11]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

#Set slide title
title_placeholder = slide.shapes.title
title_placeholder.text = "Slide Title"

#Augment placeholder to be a table
placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]
graphic_frame = placeholder.insert_table(rows = in_rows+1, cols = in_cols)
table = graphic_frame.table
#table.apply_style = 'MediumStyle4'
#table.apply_style = 'D7AC3CCA-C797-4891-BE02-D94E43425B78'

#Set column widths
table.columns[0].width = Inches(2.23)
table.columns[1].width = Inches(0.9)
table.columns[2].width = Inches(0.6)
table.columns[3].width = Inches(2)
table.columns[4].width = Inches(0.6)
table.columns[5].width = Inches(0.6)
table.columns[6].width = Inches(0.6)
table.columns[7].width = Inches(0.6)
table.columns[8].width = Inches(0.6)
table.columns[9].width = Inches(0.6)
#total_width = 2.23+0.9+0.6+2+0.6*6

#Insert data into table
for rows in xrange(in_rows+1):
    for cols in xrange(in_cols):
        #Write column titles
        if rows == 0:
            table.cell(rows, cols).text = header[cols]
            table.cell(rows, cols).text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size=Pt(14)
            table.cell(rows, cols).text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255)
            table.cell(rows, cols).fill.solid()
            table.cell(rows, cols).fill.fore_color.rgb=RGBColor(0, 58, 111) 
        #Write rest of table entries
        else:
            table.cell(rows, cols).text = str("{0:.2f}".format(df.iloc[rows-1,cols]))
            table.cell(rows, cols).text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size=Pt(10)
            table.cell(rows, cols).text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)
            table.cell(rows, cols).fill.solid()
            table.cell(rows, cols).fill.fore_color.rgb=RGBColor(255, 255, 255)

#Write Table to File
prs.save('C:/Desktop/test.pptx')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe not really clean code but allowed me to adjust all borders of all cells in a table:

```
from pptx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement

def SubElement(parent, tagname, **kwargs):
        element = OxmlElement(tagname)
        element.attrib.update(kwargs)
        parent.append(element)
        return element

def _set_cell_border(cell, border_color="000000", border_width='12700'):
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
    for lines in ['a:lnL','a:lnR','a:lnT','a:lnB']:
        ln = SubElement(tcPr, lines, w=border_width, cap='flat', cmpd='sng', algn='ctr')
        solidFill = SubElement(ln, 'a:solidFill')
        srgbClr = SubElement(solidFill, 'a:srgbClr', val=border_color)
        prstDash = SubElement(ln, 'a:prstDash', val='solid')
        round_ = SubElement(ln, 'a:round')
        headEnd = SubElement(ln, 'a:headEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
        tailEnd = SubElement(ln, 'a:tailEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
```

Based on this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-pptx/UTkdemIZICw

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I implemented this code, but noticed that nothing was happening in the resulting powerpoint. I found the cause to be that I called `cell.fill.background()` on the cell previously to calling this function. This causes the function to silently do nothing (ie. leave the noFill in the xml)

Comment: I asked how to get rid of the grid completely yesterday and found the answer as well. By changing 'a:solidFill' to 'a:NoFill' (you can omit the lines after this) you can make this work.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else comes across this issue again, some changes should be made to the solution posted by [JuuLes87](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295481/12065696) to avoid that Microsoft Office PowerPoint requires to repair the generated presentation.

After carefully inspecting the xml string of the table generated by pptx, I found that the requirement to repair the presentation seemed to be due to the duplicated nodes of 'a:lnL' or 'a:lnR' or 'a:lnT' or 'a:lnB' in the children elements of 'a:tcPr'. So we only need to remove nodes of ['a:lnL','a:lnR','a:lnT','a:lnB'] before these nodes are inserted as below.

```
from pptx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement

def SubElement(parent, tagname, **kwargs):
    element = OxmlElement(tagname)
    element.attrib.update(kwargs)
    parent.append(element)
    return element

def _set_cell_border(cell, border_color="000000", border_width='12700'):
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
    for lines in ['a:lnL','a:lnR','a:lnT','a:lnB']:
        
        # Every time before a node is inserted, the nodes with the same tag should be removed.
        tag = lines.split(":")[-1]
        for e in tcPr.getchildren():
            if tag in str(e.tag):
                tcPr.remove(e)
        # end

        ln = SubElement(tcPr, lines, w=border_width, cap='flat', cmpd='sng', algn='ctr')
        solidFill = SubElement(ln, 'a:solidFill')
        srgbClr = SubElement(solidFill, 'a:srgbClr', val=border_color)
        prstDash = SubElement(ln, 'a:prstDash', val='solid')
        round_ = SubElement(ln, 'a:round')
        headEnd = SubElement(ln, 'a:headEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
        tailEnd = SubElement(ln, 'a:tailEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
```

Comment: I am also using your formula on merge cells, but seems to not work. Is there a particular change I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time figuring out why this wasn't working. For anyone else struggling with this, I had to add the following to the end of the function:

```
return cell
```

When using, you want to use the function as such:

```
cell = _set_cell_border(cell)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution (from a google forum user, with an adjustment the the border_width arg) worked for me:

```
def SubElement(parent, tagname, **kwargs):
    element = OxmlElement(tagname)
    element.attrib.update(kwargs)
    parent.append(element)
    return element

def _set_cell_border(cell, border_color="FFFFFF", border_width='127000'):
    """ Hack function to enable the setting of border width and border color
        - left border
        - right border
        - top border
        - bottom border
    """
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()

    # Left Cell Border
    lnL = SubElement(tcPr, 'a:lnL', w=border_width, cap='flat', cmpd='sng', algn='ctr')
    lnL_solidFill = SubElement(lnL, 'a:solidFill')
    lnL_srgbClr = SubElement(lnL_solidFill, 'a:srgbClr', val=border_color)
    lnL_prstDash = SubElement(lnL, 'a:prstDash', val='solid')
    lnL_round_ = SubElement(lnL, 'a:round')
    lnL_headEnd = SubElement(lnL, 'a:headEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
    lnL_tailEnd = SubElement(lnL, 'a:tailEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')

    # Right Cell Border
    lnR = SubElement(tcPr, 'a:lnR', w=border_width, cap='flat', cmpd='sng', algn='ctr')
    lnR_solidFill = SubElement(lnR, 'a:solidFill')
    lnR_srgbClr = SubElement(lnR_solidFill, 'a:srgbClr', val=border_color)
    lnR_prstDash = SubElement(lnR, 'a:prstDash', val='solid')
    lnR_round_ = SubElement(lnR, 'a:round')
    lnR_headEnd = SubElement(lnR, 'a:headEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
    lnR_tailEnd = SubElement(lnR, 'a:tailEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')

    # Top Cell Border
    lnT = SubElement(tcPr, 'a:lnT', w=border_width, cap='flat', cmpd='sng', algn='ctr')
    lnT_solidFill = SubElement(lnT, 'a:solidFill')
    lnT_srgbClr = SubElement(lnT_solidFill, 'a:srgbClr', val=border_color)
    lnT_prstDash = SubElement(lnT, 'a:prstDash', val='solid')
    lnT_round_ = SubElement(lnT, 'a:round')
    lnT_headEnd = SubElement(lnT, 'a:headEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
    lnT_tailEnd = SubElement(lnT, 'a:tailEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')

    # Bottom Cell Border
    lnB = SubElement(tcPr, 'a:lnB', w=border_width, cap='flat', cmpd='sng', algn='ctr')
    lnB_solidFill = SubElement(lnB, 'a:solidFill')
    lnB_srgbClr = SubElement(lnB_solidFill, 'a:srgbClr', val=border_color)
    lnB_prstDash = SubElement(lnB, 'a:prstDash', val='solid')
    lnB_round_ = SubElement(lnB, 'a:round')
    lnB_headEnd = SubElement(lnB, 'a:headEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
    lnB_tailEnd = SubElement(lnB, 'a:tailEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')

    #loop through all cells. apply before setting any cell colors/fonts/..
    for cell in table.table.iter_cells():
         _set_cell_border(cell)
```