# python pptx adding border to text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-pptx

I am using Python 2.7 with python pptx 
and need to add border to some text i am writing.

I need it to be a simple box in a color that i specify around the text

I found [here](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html) the text related object but I don't find any mention to what I need, and I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610829/python-pptx-changing-table-style-or-adding-borders-to-cells) a similar question about tables but with no answer...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what objects in Word can have a border. I expect a paragraph can, but not sure a run of text can. You can determine this pretty quickly by experimenting with the Word UI.

In any case, that feature is not implemented in `python-docx` yet.

Comment: so i can't use python-pptx to add a border to a paragraph yet?

Comment: No. At least not using the API. You can use the `Paragraph` object to get the `<w:p>` element (`p = paragraph._p`) and manipulate the XML for the paragraph directly using lxml calls. This is what folks generally do to write workaround extensions.